# Custom domain gives error 400 with Azure CDN

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to access my content on my Azure CDN via a a custom domain (cdn.mydomain.com/pictures/logo.jpg)

But I get an error 400:

```
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidUri</Code>
    <Message>
        The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server. RequestId:8fa9ea29-e46f-4053-a902-5707d19e1520 Time:2011-05-13T09:40:08.3459953Z
    </Message>
    <UriPath>http://cdn.mydomain.com/pictures/logo.jpg</UriPath>
</Error>
```

However, when accessing through the URL given på Azure (accountname.blob.core.windows.net) things work perfectly.

The storage is created a few weeks ago, and so is the custom domain. I've created a CNAME and pointed it to accountname.blob.core.windows.net.

How to show content from my custom domain?

EDIT:  I tried pointing my custom domain to xxxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net. Now, all I get is a blank page. I can't seem to figure out where to point my custom domain. No matter what, I end up with a http error 400.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you followed the CName mapping instructions in http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-the-new-windows-azure-cdn-with-a-custom-domain ?

Comment: This must be the most correct answer, because the domain should actually point at xxxxxxx.vo.msecnd.net. I guess the blank pages was some kind of cache or something.

Comment: @Stuart, i did as per the blog, still i get 404

http://az697612.vo.msecnd.net/static/181b6e70/css/farbtastic.css
&
http://static.int.runway2street.com/static/181b6e70/css/farbtastic.css

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the Azure CDN, but I suggest you verify that your CNAME is set up properly.  Try [dig](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Tools/dig.php) your DNS name and check that it includes something like

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
cdn.mydomain.com.   7200    IN  CNAME   accountname.blob.core.windows.net.
```